# I'm trying to take a file from user in jetpack compose and storing lines of it in list like this :

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-development

```
val pickFileLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){
                            FileUri ->
                       if(FileUri != null){
                            val inputStream: InputStream = File(FileUri.getPath()).inputStream()
                            val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
                            inputStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
                        }
                    }
                    pickFileLauncher.launch("*/*")
```

but when i start the app i got this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Launcher has not been initialized

I have searched for error and the solution was use SideEffect to run but that's not working.

Comment: InputStream is = getContentResolver(). openInputStream(FileUrl);

Comment: @blackapps you mean i should replace whole code with this? or just InputStream variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, Firstly you can not call the **launcher** directly by creating and calling it in **Jetpack Compose**. Because it will take time to launch and get results.

So it would be best if you used **`SideEffect`** or you can put it in **Button** Click so that it runs properly another change is you are fetching **`InputStream`** from `Uri` in the wrong way you need to make use of **`ContentResolver`** to get **`InputStream`** of that file from Uri.

Here is a working example. Choose The File And It will Display Line Count In Text.

```
@Composable
fun Stack035() {
    
    val linesCount = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val pickFileLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { FileUri ->
            if (FileUri != null) {
                val inputStream: InputStream? =context.contentResolver.openInputStream(FileUri)
                val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
                inputStream?.bufferedReader()?.forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
                linesCount.value = lineList.size
                Log.e("TAG", "Stack035: $FileUri")
            }
        }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = {
            pickFileLauncher.launch("*/*")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Open File")
        }

        Text(text = "How many lines in the files == ${linesCount.value}")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rememberLauncherForActivityResult() helps your launcher retain configuration changes. Just like if you rotate the screen, it will help the launcher to maintain its state.
It is always a good practice to initialize the pickFileLauncher variable before calling the 'launch' method. And also ensure to initialize it at the place where your Android Component is in onCreate/onCreateView lifecycle phase.
I hope it will solve your error. If your error persist, Kindly share more details regarding your program or the error(using logcat or debugger).